# c# to vb.net Linq conversion

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am trying to convert this to vb.net via the developerfusion conversion tool but dosent work..

using System.Linq;

```
List<A> foo = GetFooList();    // gets data
List<A> fooBorItems = foo.Where(a = > a.FName == "foobar").ToList();
```

Plz can someone convert this to vb.net form e and tell me whats this -->    =>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a predicate delegate used in an extension method. Here is the MSDN article that describes its usage:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

The appropriate usage in VB for what you've pasted would be:

```
Dim fooBorItems as  List(Of A) = foo.Where(Function(x) x.FName = "foobar").ToList()
```

Comment: This is not how a List is declared in VB.NET

Comment: @huMptyduMpty Thanks (-> from Joel Etherton). Now it is right. Previously, it was wrong :)

Comment: @varocarbas: I just got to this comment. Did I have it as `List<A>`? I've been immersed in C# all morning, and it wouldn't surprise me if I got lazy on that one.

Comment: @JoelEtherton no problem; this is something which might happen to anyone; and here was huMpty duMpty to fix it for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

`Dim fooBorItems as  List(Of A) = foo.Where(Function(a) a.Name = "foobar").ToList()`

Also please have a look at the article about [linq samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/bb688088.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Dim foobar = foo.Where(function(x) x.name = "foo").ToList()